NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.Origin while running expire snapshot on Iceberg in Databricks
While trying to run
spark.sql("CALL iceberg_catalog.system.expire_snapshots(table => 'iceberg_catalog.d11_stitch.rewards_third_party_impact_base_query',  older_than => TIMESTAMP '2024-03-06 00:00:00.000')")
to this Im getting
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o415.sql.
: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.Origin.<init>(Lscala/Option;Lscala/Option;Lscala/Option;Lscala/Option;Lscala/Option;Lscala/Option;Lscala/Option;)V
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.extensions.IcebergParserUtils$.position(IcebergSqlExtensionsAstBuilder.scala:377)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.extensions.IcebergParserUtils$.withOrigin(IcebergSqlExtensionsAstBuilder.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.extensions.IcebergSqlExtensionsAstBuilder.visitSingleStatement(IcebergSqlExtensionsAstBuilder.scala:334)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.extensions.IcebergSqlExtensionsAstBuilder.visitSingleStatement(IcebergSqlExtensionsAstBuilder.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.extensions.IcebergSqlExtensionsParser$SingleStatementContext.accept(IcebergSqlExtensionsParser.java:153)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.AbstractParseTreeVisitor.visit(AbstractParseTreeVisitor.java:18)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.extensions.IcebergSparkSqlExtensionsParser.$anonfun$parsePlan$1(IcebergSparkSqlExtensionsParser.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.extensions.IcebergSparkSqlExtensionsParser.parse(IcebergSparkSqlExtensionsParser.scala:178)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.extensions.IcebergSparkSqlExtensionsParser.parsePlan(IcebergSparkSqlExtensionsParser.scala:124)
    at com.databricks.sql.parser.DatabricksSqlParser.$anonfun$parsePlan$1(DatabricksSqlParser.scala:80)
    at com.databricks.sql.parser.DatabricksSqlParser.parse(DatabricksSqlParser.scala:101)
    at com.databricks.sql.parser.DatabricksSqlParser.parsePlan(DatabricksSqlParser.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.$anonfun$sql$2(SparkSession.scala:892)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.FrameProfiler$.record(FrameProfiler.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker.measurePhase(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:452)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.$anonfun$sql$1(SparkSession.scala:891)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:1180)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:890)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:924)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:397)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:306)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:199)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:119)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
File <command-2355211326393001>, line 1
----> 1 spark.sql("CALL iceberg_catalog.system.expire_snapshots(table => 'iceberg_catalog.d11_stitch.rewards_third_party_impact_base_query',  older_than => TIMESTAMP '2024-03-06 00:00:00.000')")
File /databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py:326, in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324 value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325 if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326     raise Py4JJavaError(
    327         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328         format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329 else:
    330     raise Py4JError(
    331         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
    332         format(target_id, ".", name, value))

I tried using databricks Runtime 14.3 and 15.3 but getting the same issue on both the runtimes.
I was able to run this successfully on 14.1
Im adding the following jars
iceberg-spark-runtime-3.5_2.12-1.5.0.jar
iceberg-aws-bundle-1.5.0.jar
